# Is there an alternative to .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, web-hosting, apache, mod-rewrite, alternative

Is there an alternative to *.htaccess*, in case the webhoster disabled the use of *.htaccess* files?

I can set some PHP variables and headers inside the PHP files but how can I perform actions like `mod_rewrite` rules and default 404 pages?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ...in case the webhoster disabled the use of .htaccess files?

If the webhost has *disabled* the use of `.htaccess` files then there is no direct alternative. (`.htaccess` = per-directory Apache config file)

`.htaccess` files are not necessary if you have access to the Apache server config. In fact, it is preferable to use the server config instead of `.htaccess` anyway, but by the sounds of it, you do not have that luxury.

> I can set some PHP variables and headers inside the PHP files

With PHP 5.3+ under CGI/FastCGI then you can use `.user.ini` files for per-directory PHP config settings. But that's just for PHP config settings, eg. `error_reporting`, `include_path`, etc. (Mind you, under CGI/FastCGI you *need* to use `.user.ini`, since you'll get a 500 internal server error if you try to use `php_flag` and `php_value` directives in .htaccess - these are for when PHP is installed as an Apache module.)

If your (shared) host has disabled `.htaccess` and you are wanting to do more that serve simple files then... find a new host.

Just to add, it's possible for the webhost to change the name used for per-directory Apache config files (ie. "`.htaccess` files") using the `AccessFileName` directive in the server config. However, I have never encountered a host that has done this and it might possibly break other software if it is changed. It is universally expected that the Apache per-directory config file is called "`.htaccess`".

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are no alternatives.

Seems this topic was discussed from another angle :
[Alternative to .htaccess (due to bad performance)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21055/alternative-to-htaccess-due-to-bad-performance)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I've used Apache and I don't use PHP but ...

You can set your own HTTP headers, redirect, and just about everything else within a programming environment that doesn't block you from accessing those files. I don't recall where in the flow .htaccess is looked at when PHP pages are executed but you would need to find out, by googling or experimenting, if you can circumvent those rules.